# A student is applying to PhD program in Computer Sciences at Harvard and MIT.

Tags: probability

> A student is applying to PhD program in Computer Sciences at Harvard and MIT. He estimates that he has two to three chances of being accepted at Harvard and two out of five chances at MIT. He further estimates the probability that he will be accepted by both with probability of one to five. What is the probability that he is accepted by MIT if he is accepted by Harvard?

I think that the answer will be P(M|H)=(1/5)/(2/3)=0.3, but **I'm confused about the condition of the problem. Why do we need to know that P(M)=2/5 if we don't use it?** Or should I prove that the events are not independent before using the formula P(M|H)? So it would be P(M and H)=P(H)·P(M|H)=1/5=0.2

I'd really appreciate a piece of adivce. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need to know independence, because the conditional probability formula is valid whether they are independent or not.

Comment: Titles are great ways to give a taste of the mathematical content of a post. Yours is currently highly misleading, as it gives the distinct impression that the post is about applying to PhD programs rather than probability. I would strongly recommend rewriting the title.

Comment: Moreover, this is a word-for-word copy of another question.  Five seconds with THE GOOGLE would have answered your question. :\

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you get the same result for $P(M\mid H)$ from 
$P(M \& H)=P(H) P(M\mid H)=1/5$
as you do from $P(M\mid H)=(1/5)/(2/3),$
since $P(H)=2/3$ is given in the problem statement.

Sometimes a problem will give you more information than you really need.
In real life you'll usually either have more than you need or not enough.
Don't worry about the "more than you need" case.